# Word translator program based on string comparison is not working properly

Tags: c, arrays, string

I made a program that reads from file `english_dictionary.txt` the 100 most frequently used words in the English language, and in `foreign_dictionary.txt` I put the translations of the respective words in a foreign language.

The content of the `.txt` files is placed in two `char *array [100]`.

Then the program reads from file `text_to_translate.txt`, that containing a text in English, and would replace the strings(words) in English with foreign ones if it finds a match. But it does not work, someone can tell me why?

Below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){

    char *foreign[100];
    int i;

    FILE *fp = fopen("foreign_dictionary.txt", "r");

    for (i = 0; i < 100; ++i){
        foreign[i] = malloc(15 * sizeof(char));
        fgets(foreign[i], 20, fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    char *english[100];

    fp = fopen("english_dictionary.txt", "r");

    for (i = 0; i < 100; ++i){
        english[i] = malloc(15 * sizeof(char));
        fgets(english[i], 20, fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
//------------------------if find a match and print the translation--------
    char *buffer = malloc(15 * sizeof(char));
    int flag = 0;
    fp = fopen("text_to_translate.txt", "r");
    while (fgets(buffer, 20, fp) != NULL){
        for (i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
            if (english[i] == buffer){
                printf("%s", foreign[i]);
                flag = 1;
            }
        if (flag == 1)
            continue;
        else
            printf("%s", buffer);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

P.S. If required, the dictionaries files are made so:

```
the
and
to
of
.
.
.
```

Comment: You scan a maximum of 20 characters into a buffer that can at most hold 15 characters:`fgets(foreign[i], 20, fp);`,`fgets(english[i], 20, fp);`,`fgets(buffer, 20, fp)`

Comment: `malloc()` for `15` and `fgets()` 20?

Comment: malloc 15 and read 20?????

Comment: Recommend making a variable `character_count` so you don't use it by hand.

Comment: `malloc(15 * ...)` and `fgets(..., 20, ...)`???????

Comment: if (english[i] == buffer) is not the way to compare strings. Take a look at [strcmp()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp)

Comment: @LPs i'll look for strcmp! Thanks!

Comment: @CoolGuy thanks for the advice! i'll allocate for 20 chars!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- **Firstly** in your code, you're doing

  ```
  english[i] == buffer
  ```

  to compare the strings but you cannot compare strings using `==` operator. You need to use [`strcmp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) instead.
- **Second** , [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) reads and stores the trailing `newline`. It is always better to strip them off manually, most of the time they cause failure in *string* comparison.
- **Lastly** you're allocating `15` bytes to the buffer which you're supplying to `fgets()` while the maximum reading limit for `fgets()` is 19 (1 less than supplied). This can create  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) by buffer overrun, if the input is having more than 14 `char`s. Moreover `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to produce `1` in `C`. You can just drop  that part.

---

**Word of advice:** Regarding the design of this program, I feel there is one more bug. You never check for the success of `fgets()`, just reading the files unconditionally for 100 times and later using those values. This can create two issues.

1. Some of the content can effectively become `NULL`. So, later while using those values, again you'll face UB.
2. If you're looping for fixed number of iterations with fixed size, IMHO, there is no *requirement* for using dynamic memory allocation.

Change your approach a bit, like

- Create one temporary buffer array of enough length.
- Read the input to that temp array using `fgets()`
- Check for `fgets()` success (non-`NULL` return value)

  - *if not `NULL`*

    - strip the input of the last `newline`
    - calculate the length required to hold the string
    - allocate dynamic memory to the pointer array
    - copy the input
  - *if `NULL`*,

    - it refers end-of-file, there is nothing more to read, so you can come out of the loop to read the input for that particular file.

Comment: Thanks @Gopi for the correction. Appreciate it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

`if (english[i] == buffer)` is not the way to compare strings.

Take a look at [strcmp()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp)

You should code something like:

```
if (strcmp(english[i], buffer) == 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's have a closer look! What does this `english[i] == buffer` do?

As you know type of `buffer` is a pointer to a `char`. All pointers are just an address. And addresses are of type numbers. For example `0xff432354` points to a memory location indexed by this number. Thus when you write `buffer == foo`, computers actually compare the address numbers themselves not their contents.

In you case, you should compare their contents instead of their addresses. Therefore the function `strcmp` does this for you.